Use two Loki client for one server
I have a server that generates two types of log files:

/etc/logs/long-retention-logs.json, which I need to store in Loki server number 1
/etc/logs/short-retention-logs.json, which I need to store in Loki server number 2

Is it possible to configure Promtail to handle this setup within a single configuration?
